# how to send key from my program to external program - winCE

Tags: c#, windows-ce, sendkeys

how i can send key from my C# program to external program ?

ex: i send "G" to external program that has textbox

how to do it ? in C# (winCE)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText)

```
// Get a handle to an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
    string lpWindowName);

// Activate an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// Send a series of key presses to the Calculator application.
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get a handle to the Calculator application. The window class
    // and window name were obtained using the Spy++ tool.
    IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow("SciCalc", "Calculator");

    // Verify that Calculator is a running process.
    if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
        return;
    }

    // Make Calculator the foreground application and send it 
    // a set of calculations.
    SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
    SendKeys.SendWait("111");
    SendKeys.SendWait("*");
    SendKeys.SendWait("11");
    SendKeys.SendWait("=");
}
```

Comment: thank's for the help, but it dont work on winCE, i get error: The name 'SendKeys' does not exist in the current context

Comment: `[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);`

Comment: Make sure to add an assembly reference to System.Windows.Forms