# Close MessageBox on Windows Mobile application after several seconds (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Is there a way to close MessageBox after several seconds in Windows Mobile application (C# application)?

There are so many examples with SendKeys Class, but none of them works on Windows Mobile, and it creates an error:

The name 'SendKeys' does not exist in the current context

I have checked 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519006/how-to-send-key-from-my-program-to-external-program-wince

etc.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by adding Panel component (with Label message) that emulates Message box. So it can be set to invisible after few seconds by Timer component.

Also, I added one more action to it - it will be set as invisible if end user press it.

Answer (score 1):

I simply built my own and added a Timer that invokes close() (it also can use an event handler to call close also).  Easy, straight forward, and it works.

Comment: I think that's about the only option, too.

Comment: But close() what? How to reference to MessageBox?